# How to close the Qnamker dialog while using multiturn qna kb and LUIS with the help of orchestrator

Tags: c#, botframework, chatbot, azure-bot-service, azure-qna-maker

I am using orchestrator by Microsoft bot framework SDK. I am using LUIS and Multiturn prompt QnA maker in parallel. Iam using the samples provided https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/49.qnamaker-all-features. In this sample after running a question through orchestrator and Qnamaker, the Qnamaker dialog does not end and thereby luis model can't be triggered. How to end the Qnamker dialog. and it gives the error as shown here. `value:"System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'turn' does not match memory scopes:[] (Parameter 'key') at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Memory.DialogStateManager.set_Item(String key, Object value)` for the question asked second time.

[image]

This is the image regarding the errors observed in Emulator while testing the bot.

Comment: I think this might be related to a bug--see issue filed in the [botframework-samples repo](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/issues/3194)